# How do I display a data from another table based on Auth user in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, Users and Statements. I need to display monthly statements for the currently logged user.

User Model

```
public function statements()
{
return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Statement','account_number','name');
}
```

Statement Model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'account_number';

public $incrementing = false;

protected $keyType = 'string';
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User','account_number','name');
}
```

User Tabe

```
id
name // (ex: 01-234567 and used as username for login)
accname
email
password
```

Statement Table

```
id
account_number
month
bill
due
```

How can I display the monthly data in a datatable and also the current month data in a separate div in my blade file.

I'm new to laravel so kindly guide me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is already working you just need to get the Auth user and the statement. Something like this:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$statements = $user->statements // this is a statements collection;
```

Comment: I've updated my question sir. I'm new so i don't quite get how to display the data on the blade file or do i need to put anything on controller and or model

Comment: In this case you dont really need to use the controller more than to return your desired view. On your blade file, you can access the data from the logged user with 
`{{ Auth::user() }}`. I suppose you need to display the statements on a table, so you just need to use a 
`@foreach(Auth::user()->statements as $statement) do whatever you want here @endforeach`

Comment: I recomend you to read laravel's documentation. Its understandable and has many examples

Comment: Thank you! it worked. Now, how can i display a data for a single row? let's say for the month of december for example.

Comment: you can use the method `where()` from laravel to manipulate collections. Just type `Auth::user()->statements->where('month', 'december')`.
Read more about: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: Sir last question, how do i display the latest row based on my due_date field on statement table?

Comment: you can use `Auth::user()->statements->sortByDesc('due')->first()`